# Batch Space user input

Tags: input, batch-file, space

I'm writing a program which asks your name when you open it. The problem is that you can't have any spaces on your name, and I'd like to have spaces in my full name.

Anyway, here is my code: (How can I make that it wont just close if the user puts a space in his name?)

```
@echo off 
title Who are you?
cls 
:name
echo Who are you?
set /p name=
if %name% == %name% goto nameconfirm
exit
:nameconfirm
echo Nice to meet you, %name%
pause
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put  quotes arround the set variable when comparing:

```
if "%name%" == "%name%" goto nameconfirm
```

Think this should work.

Quotes are always good when working with spaces.